# Escaped # in URLs, sitemap and handling by Google crawler

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap, url-fragment

We have a large set of URLs of which some contain a hash character. The hash is **not** to indicate a fragment, but part of the URL path, so we escape the hash by `%23`, e.g.

```
http://example.com/example%231
http://example.com/another-example%232
…
```

Our `sitemap.xml` lists these URLs as follows:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/example%231</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/another-example%232</loc>
  </url>
  <!-- and so on … -->
</urlset>
```

Now, the Google Search Console reports `404` errors for the following URLs:

```
http://example.com/example
http://example.com/another-example
```

Note, that the strings after the `%23` got stripped away. I would understand this behavior, if the sitemap contained e.g. `http://example.com/example#1`, but we’re intentionally encoding the hash (`http://example.com/example%231`).

Is there anything I might be misunderstanding, or are there any special rules for escaping within `sitemap.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Google [don't want you to use fragments in that way](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-no-url-fragments-23449.html). They do, however, still see them as actual fragment identifiers, e.g. direct links from a search result to multiple subheadings of Wikipedia articles.

So Google probably interprets your hashes as fragment IDs, and therefore strips them from your URLs, thereby getting 404s.

[XML Sitemaps follow](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) usual escaping set out in [RSC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). There's some history around [Google's deprecated](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) use of `!#` URLs for Ajax that may be useful background.