# Google Search Console and Angular Hash

Tags: angular, indexing, google-search-console

I'm having this specific problem between the Google Search Console and my Website (angular)

So i have this url:
http://www.jmci.com.ar/barrios.html#/complejo/San_Matias

The search console only index http://www.jmci.com.ar/barrios.html

Analitycs also show http://www.jmci.com.ar/barrios.html when i look the real-time feature... so i cant even know where are my clients interests...

I need to be indexed right but i cant find any solution... (someone sended me this link, the issue is similar, but not exactly the same... https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

If someone search "Complejo San Matias" i need to be in the index...

[Search Conosole Image . Sended vs Indexed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6bpa.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Google views the `#` as a fragment identifier, and therefore strips them from your URLs.

See also [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49628451/1706837).